# I can't get window.getComputedStyle work

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to javascript and I am trying to learn but I got into some trouble.
What I am trying to do is to make a tooltip plugin (just to play around with javascript to get familiar). Everything works fine except when I am trying to make tooltip arrows to be same color as tooltip background color.I only tested it in latest versions of modern browsers, I don't want to be cross-browser , but at least to work in latest versions.
 
It works fine in Firefox, in webkit based browsers doesn't even add a style attribute to arrows , and in IE return black for arrow-border and transparent for arrow even if these properties are computed as expected.
[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/35v36o3z/1/)
I will add here only the code which I think is relative to the question , but you'll find all code in fiddle.
Javascript:

```
this.arrow = document.createElement('div');
  this.arrow.className = 'arrow';
  this.arrowBorder = document.createElement('div');
  this.arrowBorder.className = 'arrow-border';
  var bg = getComputedStyle(this.tooltip).backgroundColor,
  br = getComputedStyle(this.tooltip).borderTopColor &&
      getComputedStyle(this.tooltip).borderLeftColor &&
      getComputedStyle(this.tooltip).borderBottomColor &&
      getComputedStyle(this.tooltip).borderRightColor ||
      getComputedStyle(this.tooltip).borderColor;
  switch (this.options.position){
    case 'top-right':
    this.arrow.style.borderTopColor = bg;
    this.arrowBorder.style.borderTopColor = br;

    this.arrow.style.left = this.el.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px' ;
    this.arrowBorder.style.left = this.el.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px' ;
    break;

    case 'right':
    this.arrow.style.borderRightColor = bg;
    this.arrowBorder.style.borderRightColor = br;

    this.arrow.style.top = this.el.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px' ;
    this.arrowBorder.style.top = this.el.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px' ;
    break;

    case 'bottom-right':
    this.arrow.style.borderBottomColor = bg,
    this.arrowBorder.style.borderBottomColor = br;

    this.arrow.style.left = this.el.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
    this.arrowBorder.style.left = this.el.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
    break;

    case 'left':
    this.arrow.style.borderLeftColor = bg;
    this.arrowBorder.style.borderLeftColor = br;

    this.arrow.style.top = this.el.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px' ;
    this.arrowBorder.style.top = this.el.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px' ;
    break;

  }
```

Css:

```
.tooltip{
  position:absolute;
  padding:5px;
  pointer-events:none;
  cursor:initial;
  z-index:1;
  border:1px solid #999;
  background:#333;
}
.show{
  pointer-events:auto;
}
.arrow,
.arrow-border{
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  width:0;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  border-color:transparent;
  border-style:solid;
}
.arrow{
  z-index:2;
}
.arrow-border{
  z-index:1;
}
.top-right .arrow,
.top-right .arrow-border,
.bottom-right .arrow,
.bottom-right .arrow-border{
  -ms-transform:translate3d(-50%,0,0);
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(-50%,0,0);
  transform:translate3d(-50%,0,0);
}
.left .arrow,
.left .arrow-border,
.right .arrow,
.right .arrow-border{
  -ms-transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);
  transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);
}
/*top*/
.top-right .arrow{
  bottom:-5px;
  border-width:5px 5px 0 5px;
}
.top-right .arrow-border{
  bottom:-6px;
  border-width:6px 6px 0 6px;
}
/*right*/
.right .arrow{
  left:-5px;
  border-width:5px 5px 5px 0;
}
.right .arrow-border{
  left:-6px;
  border-width:6px 6px 6px 0;
}
/*bottom*/
.bottom-right .arrow{
  top:-5px;
  border-width:0 5px 5px 5px;
}
.bottom-right .arrow-border{
  top:-6px;
  border-width:0 6px 6px 6px;
}
/*left*/
.left .arrow{
  right:-5px;
  border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;
}
.left .arrow-border{
  right:-6px;
  border-width:6px 0 6px 6px;
}<br>
```

Html:

```
<p><!-- -->.... <a class='el1' data-effect='fade-and-drop' href='#' data-tooltip="Tooltip Content"...<!-- --></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any confirming source or documentation for this, but in my experience with WebKit, all or almost all style attributes returned by `getComputedStyle` are only available after an element has been added to the DOM tree.
And you fetch the computed style of `this.tooltip` before adding it to the DOM tree as far as I can see.

You can check how `getComputedStyle` behaves in your browser by running the following script in your console:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
console.log(JSON.stringify(getComputedStyle(div))); // not part of the DOM tree yet
document.body.appendChild(div);
console.log(JSON.stringify(getComputedStyle(div))); // part of the DOM tree
```

I get the following output:

```js
{"alignmentBaseline":"","background":"","backgroundAttachment":"","backgroundBlendMode":"","backgroundClip":"","backgroundColor":"","backgroundImage":"","backgroundOrigin":"","backgroundPosition":"","backgroundPositionX":"","backgroundPositionY":"","backgroundRepeat":"","backgroundRepeatX":"","backgroundRepeatY":"","backgroundSize":"","baselineShift":"","border":"","borderBottom":"","borderBottomColor":"","borderBottomLeftRadius":"","borderBottomRightRadius":"","borderBottomStyle":"","borderBottomWidth":"","borderCollapse":"","borderColor":"","borderImage":"","borderImageOutset":"","borderImageRepeat":"","borderImageSlice":"","borderImageSource":"","borderImageWidth":"","borderLeft":"","borderLeftColor":"","borderLeftStyle":"","borderLeftWidth":"","borderRadius":"","borderRight":"","borderRightColor":"","borderRightStyle":"","borderRightWidth":"","borderSpacing":"","borderStyle":"","borderTop":"","borderTopColor":"","borderTopLeftRadius":"","borderTopRightRadius":"","borderTopStyle":"","borderTopWidth":"","borderWidth":"","bottom":"","boxShadow":"","boxSizing":"","bufferedRendering":"","captionSide":"","clear":"","clip":"","clipPath":"","clipRule":"","color":"","colorInterpolation":"","colorInterpolationFilters":"","colorProfile":"","colorRendering":"","content":"","counterIncrement":"","counterReset":"","cursor":"","direction":"","display":"","dominantBaseline":"","emptyCells":"","enableBackground":"","fill":"","fillOpacity":"","fillRule":"","filter":"","float":"","floodColor":"","floodOpacity":"","font":"","fontFamily":"","fontSize":"","fontStretch":"","fontStyle":"","fontVariant":"","fontWeight":"","glyphOrientationHorizontal":"","glyphOrientationVertical":"","height":"","imageRendering":"","isolation":"","kerning":"","left":"","letterSpacing":"","lightingColor":"","lineHeight":"","listStyle":"","listStyleImage":"","listStylePosition":"","listStyleType":"","margin":"","marginBottom":"","marginLeft":"","marginRight":"","marginTop":"","marker":"","markerEnd":"","markerMid":"","markerStart":"","mask":"","maskType":"","maxHeight":"","maxWidth":"","minHeight":"","minWidth":"","mixBlendMode":"","objectFit":"","opacity":"","orphans":"","outline":"","outlineColor":"","outlineOffset":"","outlineStyle":"","outlineWidth":"","overflow":"","overflowWrap":"","overflowX":"","overflowY":"","padding":"","paddingBottom":"","paddingLeft":"","paddingRight":"","paddingTop":"","page":"","pageBreakAfter":"","pageBreakBefore":"","pageBreakInside":"","paintOrder":"","pointerEvents":"","position":"","quotes":"","resize":"","right":"","shapeRendering":"","size":"","speak":"","src":"","stopColor":"","stopOpacity":"","stroke":"","strokeDasharray":"","strokeDashoffset":"","strokeLinecap":"","strokeLinejoin":"","strokeMiterlimit":"","strokeOpacity":"","strokeWidth":"","tabSize":"","tableLayout":"","textAlign":"","textAnchor":"","textDecoration":"","textIndent":"","textLineThrough":"","textLineThroughColor":"","textLineThroughMode":"","textLineThroughStyle":"","textLineThroughWidth":"","textOverflow":"","textOverline":"","textOverlineColor":"","textOverlineMode":"","textOverlineStyle":"","textOverlineWidth":"","textRendering":"","textShadow":"","textTransform":"","textUnderline":"","textUnderlineColor":"","textUnderlineMode":"","textUnderlineStyle":"","textUnderlineWidth":"","top":"","transition":"","transitionDelay":"","transitionDuration":"","transitionProperty":"","transitionTimingFunction":"","unicodeBidi":"","unicodeRange":"","vectorEffect":"","verticalAlign":"","visibility":"","webkitAlignContent":"","webkitAlignItems":"","webkitAlignSelf":"","webkitAlt":"","webkitAnimation":"","webkitAnimationDelay":"","webkitAnimationDirection":"","webkitAnimationDuration":"","webkitAnimationFillMode":"","webkitAnimationIterationCount":"","webkitAnimationName":"","webkitAnimationPlayState":"","webkitAnimationTimingFunction":"","webkitAppearance":"","webkitAspectRatio":"","webkitBackfaceVisibility":"","webkitBackgroundClip":"","webkitBackgroundComposite":"","webkitBackgroundOrigin":"","webkitBackgroundSize":"","webkitBorderAfter":"","webkitBorderAfterColor":"","webkitBorderAfterStyle":"","webkitBorderAfterWidth":"","webkitBorderBefore":"","webkitBorderBeforeColor":"","webkitBorderBeforeStyle":"","webkitBorderBeforeWidth":"","webkitBorderEnd":"","webkitBorderEndColor":"","webkitBorderEndStyle":"","webkitBorderEndWidth":"","webkitBorderFit":"","webkitBorderHorizontalSpacing":"","webkitBorderImage":"","webkitBorderRadius":"","webkitBorderStart":"","webkitBorderStartColor":"","webkitBorderStartStyle":"","webkitBorderStartWidth":"","webkitBorderVerticalSpacing":"","webkitBoxAlign":"","webkitBoxDecorationBreak":"","webkitBoxDirection":"","webkitBoxFlex":"","webkitBoxFlexGroup":"","webkitBoxLines":"","webkitBoxOrdinalGroup":"","webkitBoxOrient":"","webkitBoxPack":"","webkitBoxReflect":"","webkitBoxShadow":"","webkitClipPath":"","webkitColorCorrection":"","webkitColumnAxis":"","webkitColumnBreakAfter":"","webkitColumnBreakBefore":"","webkitColumnBreakInside":"","webkitColumnCount":"","webkitColumnFill":"","webkitColumnGap":"","webkitColumnProgression":"","webkitColumnRule":"","webkitColumnRuleColor":"","webkitColumnRuleStyle":"","webkitColumnRuleWidth":"","webkitColumnSpan":"","webkitColumnWidth":"","webkitColumns":"","webkitCursorVisibility":"","webkitDashboardRegion":"","webkitFilter":"","webkitFlex":"","webkitFlexBasis":"","webkitFlexDirection":"","webkitFlexFlow":"","webkitFlexGrow":"","webkitFlexShrink":"","webkitFlexWrap":"","webkitFlowFrom":"","webkitFlowInto":"","webkitFontFeatureSettings":"","webkitFontKerning":"","webkitFontSizeDelta":"","webkitFontSmoothing":"","webkitFontVariantLigatures":"","webkitHyphenateCharacter":"","webkitHyphenateLimitAfter":"","webkitHyphenateLimitBefore":"","webkitHyphenateLimitLines":"","webkitHyphens":"","webkitJustifyContent":"","webkitJustifySelf":"","webkitLineAlign":"","webkitLineBoxContain":"","webkitLineBreak":"","webkitLineClamp":"","webkitLineGrid":"","webkitLineSnap":"","webkitLocale":"","webkitLogicalHeight":"","webkitLogicalWidth":"","webkitMarginAfter":"","webkitMarginAfterCollapse":"","webkitMarginBefore":"","webkitMarginBeforeCollapse":"","webkitMarginBottomCollapse":"","webkitMarginCollapse":"","webkitMarginEnd":"","webkitMarginStart":"","webkitMarginTopCollapse":"","webkitMarquee":"","webkitMarqueeDirection":"","webkitMarqueeIncrement":"","webkitMarqueeRepetition":"","webkitMarqueeSpeed":"","webkitMarqueeStyle":"","webkitMask":"","webkitMaskBoxImage":"","webkitMaskBoxImageOutset":"","webkitMaskBoxImageRepeat":"","webkitMaskBoxImageSlice":"","webkitMaskBoxImageSource":"","webkitMaskBoxImageWidth":"","webkitMaskClip":"","webkitMaskComposite":"","webkitMaskImage":"","webkitMaskOrigin":"","webkitMaskPosition":"","webkitMaskPositionX":"","webkitMaskPositionY":"","webkitMaskRepeat":"","webkitMaskRepeatX":"","webkitMaskRepeatY":"","webkitMaskSize":"","webkitMaskSourceType":"","webkitMaxLogicalHeight":"","webkitMaxLogicalWidth":"","webkitMinLogicalHeight":"","webkitMinLogicalWidth":"","webkitNbspMode":"","webkitOrder":"","webkitPaddingAfter":"","webkitPaddingBefore":"","webkitPaddingEnd":"","webkitPaddingStart":"","webkitPerspective":"","webkitPerspectiveOrigin":"","webkitPerspectiveOriginX":"","webkitPerspectiveOriginY":"","webkitPrintColorAdjust":"","webkitRegionBreakAfter":"","webkitRegionBreakBefore":"","webkitRegionBreakInside":"","webkitRegionFragment":"","webkitRtlOrdering":"","webkitRubyPosition":"","webkitShapeImageThreshold":"","webkitShapeMargin":"","webkitShapeOutside":"","webkitSvgShadow":"","webkitTextCombine":"","webkitTextDecoration":"","webkitTextDecorationColor":"","webkitTextDecorationLine":"","webkitTextDecorationSkip":"","webkitTextDecorationStyle":"","webkitTextDecorationsInEffect":"","webkitTextEmphasis":"","webkitTextEmphasisColor":"","webkitTextEmphasisPosition":"","webkitTextEmphasisStyle":"","webkitTextFillColor":"","webkitTextOrientation":"","webkitTextSecurity":"","webkitTextStroke":"","webkitTextStrokeColor":"","webkitTextStrokeWidth":"","webkitTextUnderlinePosition":"","webkitTransform":"","webkitTransformOrigin":"","webkitTransformOriginX":"","webkitTransformOriginY":"","webkitTransformOriginZ":"","webkitTransformStyle":"","webkitTransition":"","webkitTransitionDelay":"","webkitTransitionDuration":"","webkitTransitionProperty":"","webkitTransitionTimingFunction":"","webkitUserDrag":"","webkitUserModify":"","webkitUserSelect":"","webkitWritingMode":"","whiteSpace":"","widows":"","width":"","wordBreak":"","wordSpacing":"","wordWrap":"","writingMode":"","zIndex":"","zoom":"","length":0}
```

and

```js
{"0":"background-attachment","1":"background-blend-mode","2":"background-clip","3":"background-color","4":"background-image","5":"background-origin","6":"background-position","7":"background-repeat","8":"background-size","9":"border-bottom-color","10":"border-bottom-left-radius","11":"border-bottom-right-radius","12":"border-bottom-style","13":"border-bottom-width","14":"border-collapse","15":"border-image-outset","16":"border-image-repeat","17":"border-image-slice","18":"border-image-source","19":"border-image-width","20":"border-left-color","21":"border-left-style","22":"border-left-width","23":"border-right-color","24":"border-right-style","25":"border-right-width","26":"border-top-color","27":"border-top-left-radius","28":"border-top-right-radius","29":"border-top-style","30":"border-top-width","31":"bottom","32":"box-shadow","33":"box-sizing","34":"caption-side","35":"clear","36":"clip","37":"color","38":"cursor","39":"direction","40":"display","41":"empty-cells","42":"float","43":"font-family","44":"font-size","45":"font-style","46":"font-variant","47":"font-weight","48":"height","49":"image-rendering","50":"left","51":"letter-spacing","52":"line-height","53":"list-style-image","54":"list-style-position","55":"list-style-type","56":"margin-bottom","57":"margin-left","58":"margin-right","59":"margin-top","60":"max-height","61":"max-width","62":"min-height","63":"min-width","64":"opacity","65":"orphans","66":"outline-color","67":"outline-offset","68":"outline-style","69":"outline-width","70":"overflow-wrap","71":"overflow-x","72":"overflow-y","73":"padding-bottom","74":"padding-left","75":"padding-right","76":"padding-top","77":"page-break-after","78":"page-break-before","79":"page-break-inside","80":"pointer-events","81":"position","82":"resize","83":"right","84":"speak","85":"table-layout","86":"tab-size","87":"text-align","88":"text-decoration","89":"-webkit-text-decoration-line","90":"-webkit-text-decoration-style","91":"-webkit-text-decoration-color","92":"-webkit-text-decoration-skip","93":"-webkit-text-underline-position","94":"text-indent","95":"text-rendering","96":"text-shadow","97":"text-overflow","98":"text-transform","99":"top","100":"transition-delay","101":"transition-duration","102":"transition-property","103":"transition-timing-function","104":"unicode-bidi","105":"vertical-align","106":"visibility","107":"white-space","108":"widows","109":"width","110":"word-break","111":"word-spacing","112":"word-wrap","113":"z-index","114":"zoom","115":"-webkit-alt","116":"-webkit-animation-delay","117":"-webkit-animation-direction","118":"-webkit-animation-duration","119":"-webkit-animation-fill-mode","120":"-webkit-animation-iteration-count","121":"-webkit-animation-name","122":"-webkit-animation-play-state","123":"-webkit-animation-timing-function","124":"-webkit-appearance","125":"-webkit-backface-visibility","126":"-webkit-background-clip","127":"-webkit-background-composite","128":"-webkit-background-origin","129":"-webkit-background-size","130":"mix-blend-mode","131":"isolation","132":"-webkit-border-fit","133":"-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing","134":"-webkit-border-image","135":"-webkit-border-vertical-spacing","136":"-webkit-box-align","137":"-webkit-box-decoration-break","138":"-webkit-box-direction","139":"-webkit-box-flex","140":"-webkit-box-flex-group","141":"-webkit-box-lines","142":"-webkit-box-ordinal-group","143":"-webkit-box-orient","144":"-webkit-box-pack","145":"-webkit-box-reflect","146":"-webkit-box-shadow","147":"-webkit-clip-path","148":"-webkit-color-correction","149":"-webkit-column-break-after","150":"-webkit-column-break-before","151":"-webkit-column-break-inside","152":"-webkit-column-axis","153":"-webkit-column-count","154":"-webkit-column-gap","155":"-webkit-column-progression","156":"-webkit-column-rule-color","157":"-webkit-column-rule-style","158":"-webkit-column-rule-width","159":"-webkit-column-span","160":"-webkit-column-width","161":"-webkit-cursor-visibility","162":"-webkit-dashboard-region","163":"-webkit-filter","164":"-webkit-align-content","165":"-webkit-align-items","166":"-webkit-align-self","167":"-webkit-flex-basis","168":"-webkit-flex-grow","169":"-webkit-flex-shrink","170":"-webkit-flex-direction","171":"-webkit-flex-wrap","172":"-webkit-justify-content","173":"-webkit-justify-self","174":"-webkit-font-kerning","175":"-webkit-font-smoothing","176":"-webkit-font-variant-ligatures","177":"-webkit-hyphenate-character","178":"-webkit-hyphenate-limit-after","179":"-webkit-hyphenate-limit-before","180":"-webkit-hyphenate-limit-lines","181":"-webkit-hyphens","182":"-webkit-line-align","183":"-webkit-line-box-contain","184":"-webkit-line-break","185":"-webkit-line-clamp","186":"-webkit-line-grid","187":"-webkit-line-snap","188":"-webkit-locale","189":"-webkit-margin-before-collapse","190":"-webkit-margin-after-collapse","191":"-webkit-marquee-direction","192":"-webkit-marquee-increment","193":"-webkit-marquee-repetition","194":"-webkit-marquee-style","195":"-webkit-mask-box-image","196":"-webkit-mask-box-image-outset","197":"-webkit-mask-box-image-repeat","198":"-webkit-mask-box-image-slice","199":"-webkit-mask-box-image-source","200":"-webkit-mask-box-image-width","201":"-webkit-mask-clip","202":"-webkit-mask-composite","203":"-webkit-mask-image","204":"-webkit-mask-origin","205":"-webkit-mask-position","206":"-webkit-mask-repeat","207":"-webkit-mask-size","208":"-webkit-mask-source-type","209":"-webkit-nbsp-mode","210":"-webkit-order","211":"-webkit-perspective","212":"-webkit-perspective-origin","213":"-webkit-print-color-adjust","214":"-webkit-rtl-ordering","215":"-webkit-shape-outside","216":"-webkit-text-combine","217":"-webkit-text-decorations-in-effect","218":"-webkit-text-emphasis-color","219":"-webkit-text-emphasis-position","220":"-webkit-text-emphasis-style","221":"-webkit-text-fill-color","222":"-webkit-text-orientation","223":"-webkit-text-security","224":"-webkit-text-stroke-color","225":"-webkit-text-stroke-width","226":"-webkit-transform","227":"-webkit-transform-origin","228":"-webkit-transform-style","229":"-webkit-transition-delay","230":"-webkit-transition-duration","231":"-webkit-transition-property","232":"-webkit-transition-timing-function","233":"-webkit-user-drag","234":"-webkit-user-modify","235":"-webkit-user-select","236":"-webkit-writing-mode","237":"-webkit-flow-into","238":"-webkit-flow-from","239":"-webkit-region-break-after","240":"-webkit-region-break-before","241":"-webkit-region-break-inside","242":"-webkit-region-fragment","243":"-webkit-shape-margin","244":"-webkit-shape-image-threshold","245":"buffered-rendering","246":"clip-path","247":"clip-rule","248":"mask","249":"filter","250":"flood-color","251":"flood-opacity","252":"lighting-color","253":"stop-color","254":"stop-opacity","255":"color-interpolation","256":"color-interpolation-filters","257":"color-rendering","258":"fill","259":"fill-opacity","260":"fill-rule","261":"marker-end","262":"marker-mid","263":"marker-start","264":"mask-type","265":"paint-order","266":"shape-rendering","267":"stroke","268":"stroke-dasharray","269":"stroke-dashoffset","270":"stroke-linecap","271":"stroke-linejoin","272":"stroke-miterlimit","273":"stroke-opacity","274":"stroke-width","275":"alignment-baseline","276":"baseline-shift","277":"dominant-baseline","278":"kerning","279":"text-anchor","280":"writing-mode","281":"glyph-orientation-horizontal","282":"glyph-orientation-vertical","283":"-webkit-svg-shadow","284":"vector-effect","alignmentBaseline":"auto","background":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box","backgroundAttachment":"scroll","backgroundBlendMode":"normal","backgroundClip":"border-box","backgroundColor":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)","backgroundImage":"none","backgroundOrigin":"padding-box","backgroundPosition":"0% 0%","backgroundPositionX":"0%","backgroundPositionY":"0%","backgroundRepeat":"repeat","backgroundRepeatX":"","backgroundRepeatY":"","backgroundSize":"auto","baselineShift":"baseline","border":"0px none rgb(34, 34, 34)","borderBottom":"0px none rgb(34, 34, 34)","borderBottomColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","borderBottomLeftRadius":"0px","borderBottomRightRadius":"0px","borderBottomStyle":"none","borderBottomWidth":"0px","borderCollapse":"separate","borderColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","borderImage":"none","borderImageOutset":"0px","borderImageRepeat":"stretch","borderImageSlice":"100%","borderImageSource":"none","borderImageWidth":"1","borderLeft":"0px none rgb(34, 34, 34)","borderLeftColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","borderLeftStyle":"none","borderLeftWidth":"0px","borderRadius":"0px","borderRight":"0px none rgb(34, 34, 34)","borderRightColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","borderRightStyle":"none","borderRightWidth":"0px","borderSpacing":"0px 0px","borderStyle":"none","borderTop":"0px none rgb(34, 34, 34)","borderTopColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","borderTopLeftRadius":"0px","borderTopRightRadius":"0px","borderTopStyle":"none","borderTopWidth":"0px","borderWidth":"0px","bottom":"auto","boxShadow":"none","boxSizing":"content-box","bufferedRendering":"auto","captionSide":"top","clear":"none","clip":"auto","clipPath":"none","clipRule":"nonzero","color":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","colorInterpolation":"srgb","colorInterpolationFilters":"linearrgb","colorProfile":"","colorRendering":"auto","content":"","counterIncrement":"","counterReset":"","cursor":"auto","direction":"ltr","display":"block","dominantBaseline":"auto","emptyCells":"show","enableBackground":"","fill":"#000000","fillOpacity":"1","fillRule":"nonzero","filter":"none","float":"none","floodColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)","floodOpacity":"1","font":"normal normal normal 13px/16.899999618530273px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif","fontFamily":"'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif","fontSize":"13px","fontStretch":"","fontStyle":"normal","fontVariant":"normal","fontWeight":"normal","glyphOrientationHorizontal":"0deg","glyphOrientationVertical":"auto","height":"0px","imageRendering":"auto","isolation":"auto","kerning":"0","left":"auto","letterSpacing":"normal","lightingColor":"rgb(255, 255, 255)","lineHeight":"16.899999618530273px","listStyle":"disc outside none","listStyleImage":"none","listStylePosition":"outside","listStyleType":"disc","margin":"0px","marginBottom":"0px","marginLeft":"0px","marginRight":"0px","marginTop":"0px","marker":"","markerEnd":"none","markerMid":"none","markerStart":"none","mask":"none","maskType":"luminance","maxHeight":"none","maxWidth":"none","minHeight":"0px","minWidth":"0px","mixBlendMode":"normal","objectFit":"fill","opacity":"1","orphans":"auto","outline":"rgb(34, 34, 34) none 0px","outlineColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","outlineOffset":"0px","outlineStyle":"none","outlineWidth":"0px","overflow":"visible","overflowWrap":"normal","overflowX":"visible","overflowY":"visible","padding":"0px","paddingBottom":"0px","paddingLeft":"0px","paddingRight":"0px","paddingTop":"0px","page":"","pageBreakAfter":"auto","pageBreakBefore":"auto","pageBreakInside":"auto","paintOrder":"normal","pointerEvents":"auto","position":"static","quotes":"","resize":"none","right":"auto","shapeRendering":"auto","size":"","speak":"normal","src":"","stopColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)","stopOpacity":"1","stroke":"none","strokeDasharray":"none","strokeDashoffset":"0","strokeLinecap":"butt","strokeLinejoin":"miter","strokeMiterlimit":"4","strokeOpacity":"1","strokeWidth":"1","tabSize":"8","tableLayout":"auto","textAlign":"start","textAnchor":"start","textDecoration":"none","textIndent":"0px","textLineThrough":"","textLineThroughColor":"","textLineThroughMode":"","textLineThroughStyle":"","textLineThroughWidth":"","textOverflow":"clip","textOverline":"","textOverlineColor":"","textOverlineMode":"","textOverlineStyle":"","textOverlineWidth":"","textRendering":"auto","textShadow":"none","textTransform":"none","textUnderline":"","textUnderlineColor":"","textUnderlineMode":"","textUnderlineStyle":"","textUnderlineWidth":"","top":"auto","transition":"all 0s ease 0s","transitionDelay":"0s","transitionDuration":"0s","transitionProperty":"all","transitionTimingFunction":"ease","unicodeBidi":"normal","unicodeRange":"","vectorEffect":"none","verticalAlign":"baseline","visibility":"visible","webkitAlignContent":"stretch","webkitAlignItems":"stretch","webkitAlignSelf":"stretch","webkitAlt":"''","webkitAnimation":"","webkitAnimationDelay":"0s","webkitAnimationDirection":"normal","webkitAnimationDuration":"0s","webkitAnimationFillMode":"none","webkitAnimationIterationCount":"1","webkitAnimationName":"none","webkitAnimationPlayState":"running","webkitAnimationTimingFunction":"ease","webkitAppearance":"none","webkitAspectRatio":"auto","webkitBackfaceVisibility":"visible","webkitBackgroundClip":"border-box","webkitBackgroundComposite":"source-over","webkitBackgroundOrigin":"padding-box","webkitBackgroundSize":"auto","webkitBorderAfter":"0px none rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitBorderAfterColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitBorderAfterStyle":"none","webkitBorderAfterWidth":"0px","webkitBorderBefore":"0px none rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitBorderBeforeColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitBorderBeforeStyle":"none","webkitBorderBeforeWidth":"0px","webkitBorderEnd":"0px none rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitBorderEndColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitBorderEndStyle":"none","webkitBorderEndWidth":"0px","webkitBorderFit":"border","webkitBorderHorizontalSpacing":"0px","webkitBorderImage":"none","webkitBorderRadius":"","webkitBorderStart":"0px none rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitBorderStartColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitBorderStartStyle":"none","webkitBorderStartWidth":"0px","webkitBorderVerticalSpacing":"0px","webkitBoxAlign":"stretch","webkitBoxDecorationBreak":"slice","webkitBoxDirection":"normal","webkitBoxFlex":"0","webkitBoxFlexGroup":"1","webkitBoxLines":"single","webkitBoxOrdinalGroup":"1","webkitBoxOrient":"horizontal","webkitBoxPack":"start","webkitBoxReflect":"none","webkitBoxShadow":"none","webkitClipPath":"none","webkitColorCorrection":"default","webkitColumnAxis":"auto","webkitColumnBreakAfter":"auto","webkitColumnBreakBefore":"auto","webkitColumnBreakInside":"auto","webkitColumnCount":"auto","webkitColumnFill":"balance","webkitColumnGap":"normal","webkitColumnProgression":"normal","webkitColumnRule":"0px none rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitColumnRuleColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitColumnRuleStyle":"none","webkitColumnRuleWidth":"0px","webkitColumnSpan":"none","webkitColumnWidth":"auto","webkitColumns":"auto auto","webkitCursorVisibility":"auto","webkitDashboardRegion":"","webkitFilter":"none","webkitFlex":"0 1 auto","webkitFlexBasis":"auto","webkitFlexDirection":"row","webkitFlexFlow":"row nowrap","webkitFlexGrow":"0","webkitFlexShrink":"1","webkitFlexWrap":"nowrap","webkitFlowFrom":"none","webkitFlowInto":"none","webkitFontFeatureSettings":"normal","webkitFontKerning":"auto","webkitFontSizeDelta":"","webkitFontSmoothing":"auto","webkitFontVariantLigatures":"normal","webkitHyphenateCharacter":"auto","webkitHyphenateLimitAfter":"auto","webkitHyphenateLimitBefore":"auto","webkitHyphenateLimitLines":"no-limit","webkitHyphens":"manual","webkitJustifyContent":"flex-start","webkitJustifySelf":"auto","webkitLineAlign":"none","webkitLineBoxContain":"block inline replaced","webkitLineBreak":"auto","webkitLineClamp":"none","webkitLineGrid":"none","webkitLineSnap":"none","webkitLocale":"auto","webkitLogicalHeight":"0px","webkitLogicalWidth":"2560px","webkitMarginAfter":"0px","webkitMarginAfterCollapse":"collapse","webkitMarginBefore":"0px","webkitMarginBeforeCollapse":"collapse","webkitMarginBottomCollapse":"collapse","webkitMarginCollapse":"","webkitMarginEnd":"0px","webkitMarginStart":"0px","webkitMarginTopCollapse":"collapse","webkitMarquee":"","webkitMarqueeDirection":"auto","webkitMarqueeIncrement":"6px","webkitMarqueeRepetition":"infinite","webkitMarqueeSpeed":"","webkitMarqueeStyle":"scroll","webkitMask":"","webkitMaskBoxImage":"none","webkitMaskBoxImageOutset":"0px","webkitMaskBoxImageRepeat":"stretch","webkitMaskBoxImageSlice":"0 fill","webkitMaskBoxImageSource":"none","webkitMaskBoxImageWidth":"auto","webkitMaskClip":"border-box","webkitMaskComposite":"source-over","webkitMaskImage":"none","webkitMaskOrigin":"border-box","webkitMaskPosition":"0% 0%","webkitMaskPositionX":"0%","webkitMaskPositionY":"0%","webkitMaskRepeat":"repeat","webkitMaskRepeatX":"","webkitMaskRepeatY":"","webkitMaskSize":"auto","webkitMaskSourceType":"alpha","webkitMaxLogicalHeight":"none","webkitMaxLogicalWidth":"none","webkitMinLogicalHeight":"0px","webkitMinLogicalWidth":"0px","webkitNbspMode":"normal","webkitOrder":"0","webkitPaddingAfter":"0px","webkitPaddingBefore":"0px","webkitPaddingEnd":"0px","webkitPaddingStart":"0px","webkitPerspective":"none","webkitPerspectiveOrigin":"1280px 0px","webkitPerspectiveOriginX":"","webkitPerspectiveOriginY":"","webkitPrintColorAdjust":"economy","webkitRegionBreakAfter":"auto","webkitRegionBreakBefore":"auto","webkitRegionBreakInside":"auto","webkitRegionFragment":"auto","webkitRtlOrdering":"logical","webkitRubyPosition":"before","webkitShapeImageThreshold":"0","webkitShapeMargin":"0px","webkitShapeOutside":"none","webkitSvgShadow":"none","webkitTextCombine":"none","webkitTextDecoration":"none solid rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitTextDecorationColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitTextDecorationLine":"none","webkitTextDecorationSkip":"auto","webkitTextDecorationStyle":"solid","webkitTextDecorationsInEffect":"none","webkitTextEmphasis":"","webkitTextEmphasisColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitTextEmphasisPosition":"over right","webkitTextEmphasisStyle":"none","webkitTextFillColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitTextOrientation":"vertical-right","webkitTextSecurity":"none","webkitTextStroke":"","webkitTextStrokeColor":"rgb(34, 34, 34)","webkitTextStrokeWidth":"0px","webkitTextUnderlinePosition":"auto","webkitTransform":"none","webkitTransformOrigin":"1280px 0px","webkitTransformOriginX":"","webkitTransformOriginY":"","webkitTransformOriginZ":"","webkitTransformStyle":"flat","webkitTransition":"all 0s ease 0s","webkitTransitionDelay":"0s","webkitTransitionDuration":"0s","webkitTransitionProperty":"all","webkitTransitionTimingFunction":"ease","webkitUserDrag":"auto","webkitUserModify":"read-only","webkitUserSelect":"text","webkitWritingMode":"horizontal-tb","whiteSpace":"normal","widows":"auto","width":"2560px","wordBreak":"normal","wordSpacing":"0px","wordWrap":"normal","writingMode":"lr-tb","zIndex":"auto","zoom":"1","length":285}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html) link helps you.
For IE you can try currentstyle instead of computedstyle

```
elm.currentStyle
```

All the other browsers should work with the computedstyle as well.

Comment: I tried already but didn't work, however this is  ie < 9, and I'm not interested to add support for ie8 and bellow